# Shopware marketplace: app release process

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

What are the steps for the release process and what do we have to prepare in order to successfully integrate in the Shopware marketplace (especially the pricing and marketing communications)?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to become is called "extension partner" at Shopware (older name: manufacturer)

Check this FAQ: https://docs.shopware.com/en/account-en/extension-partner or write an email to the address mentioned there: https://docs.shopware.com/en/account-en/manufacturer-area/faq

Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with Shopware, so this is not an official information :-)